# setter not retaining

Tags: ios, xcode

Why am I getting the following output:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *thePlayer;
```

Then, in .m:

```
NSLog(@"aPlayer retain count = %i",[aPlayer retainCount]);
thePlayer = aPlayer;
NSLog(@"thePlayer retain count = %i",[thePlayer retainCount]);
```

gives:

```
2012-09-18 21:52:36.787 Pocket Dungeons[56613:10a03] aPlayer retain count = 1
2012-09-18 21:52:36.788 Pocket Dungeons[56613:10a03] thePlayer retain count = 1
```

Comment: how did you declare or initialized aPlayer? Hard to assume anything based on the little code that you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the setter. You're using the ivar (the instance variable). To use the setter of a [declared property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html), use the following syntax:

```
self.thePlayer = aPlayer;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[self setThePlayer:aPlayer];
```

But in the absence of the reference to the owner object (in this case, `self`), you'll end up using the instance variable directly, and you will not invoke the setter. Thus in your original example, you're not using the setter.

By the way, that's why it's generally advised to use a different ivar name in the `@synthesize` statement, e.g.:

```
@synthesize thePlayer = _thePlayer;
```

That way, you are less likely to accidentally reference the instance variable when you meant the property. And in Xcode 4.4 or later, if you omit the `@synthesize` statement, this is the default behavior (where the synthesized instance variable will have the leading underscore).